# SVN Tags based on a DATE

Tags: svn

Can someone pls let me know how to make a tag or branch based on a certain date in SVN?

Comment: You mean like svn add tags/11.01.19 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is from your working copy, from command line, is as follows:

svn copy -r {[date-in-iso-format](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates)} [destination](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html)

For example,

```
svn copy -r {2011-01-18} http://myserver/svn/project/trunk \
           http://myserver/svn/project/tags/tag-2011-01-18 \
           -m "Tagging project on 18th Jan 2011"
```

Comment: +1 but note that this will branch from the state of the trunk as it was at the **start of the day**, i.e. midnight. The changes from later in that day will not be in the tag! If you want those changes, use  `{"2011-01-18 23:59"}` or just specify the next day `{2011-01-19}`. See the note [Is Subversion a day early?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) in the SVN book.

Comment: The -r flag also works fine copying URL to URL (server side copy).